# stucked using multiple projects inside same solution

Tags: c++11, visual-c++

I had a problem using a function from another project file to main project file inside same solution. I am working in visual studio 2017.

//1st project name:game(configuration type:.exe)

// 2nd project:engine(configuration type:static library,.lib)I made type to //
.exe but also not solved the issue.

//main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "../../engine/src/engine.h"
int main()
    {
      a::test();
      std::cin.get();
    }
```

//engine.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "../../engine/src/engine.h"
int main()
   {
a::test();
std::cin.get();
   }
```

//engine.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "engine.h"
namespace a
    {
  void test()
      {
       std::cout << "hi" << std::endl;
      } 
   }
```

I tried to build the above code. I know it can be done another way, by using static library linking. Can you help me out? Why didn't this code run? Can you point out the reason? Thank you.

Comment: You pasted the wrong contents for `engine.h`.

Comment: You also forgot to tell us what problem you have. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I got this error:
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl a::test(void)" (?test@a@@YAXXZ) referenced in function _main Game c:\Users\sandeep poudel\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Game\Game\main.obj 1 
how to avoid this error and run the program? What's actually wrong with my code?

Comment: Make the EXE project depend on the LIB. `Project > Project Dependencies`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  Thanks it worked.